# Dismiss keyboard on UITextField using Interface Builder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I've seen this, but don't remember what Jedi technique exactly was used through interface builder to dismiss uikeboard when return key is pressed. Anyone knows how to do this?

Please do not post about using UITextFieldDelegate, I know that method, I'm only interested in forcing keyboard to be dismissed on return key being hit without any additional logic or protocol conformation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Connect the IBAction with "Did End On Exit"  event in your xib of your textfield

[image]

```
-(IBAction)textFieldDidEndOnExit:(UITextField *)sender
{

}
```

Comment: view.endEditing(true)
use this code for dismissing keyboard

Answer (score 0):

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    if let touch = touches.first{
        view.endEditing(true)
       }
}
```